# Don't insert to MySQL with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating simple registration form. But I have problems with inserting data to MySQL table.

```
        if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
            $userName = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $company = $_POST['company'];

            include '../template/sql-connect.php';

            $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

            if(!db_server) { die("Query error"); }

            $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES" .
                 "('$userName', '$email', '$company')";

           if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
                 echo "INSERT failed: $query<br>" .
                 mysql_error() . "<br><br>";

            mysql_close($db_server);
        }
```

Help me to resolve this problem, please. Thank you!

Comment: Can you at least *describe* the problem?  Is there an error?  Unexpected behavior?  How is this not working?  Is it failing because of that glaring SQL injection vulnerability?

Comment: @KA_lin I have fixed this type. But page works wrong.

Comment: @David Sorry, but I can't discribe an error.. I don't see something errors on the page. I have seen post query in browser, but in phpmyadmin in my table I don't see new lines.

Comment: Quick tip: avoid mysql_ functions they are obsolete in the latest versions of PHP, use PDO instead. As it stands your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @AlexanderSeredenko: Turn on error reporting.  Check the server-side logs (both PHP and the web server).  Even just put in some `echo` statements to trace the state of the code during execution.  Do *something* to debug this.  "It doesn't work" isn't a meaningful problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually make a special file for database connection like this:

```
      <?php 
        $db_name='name'; 
        $server='server';
        $username='name'; 
        $password='pass'; 


$link=mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$db_name); 

if(!link){
die('Something went wrong'.mysqli_error($link)); 
} ?>
```

And then include it in the page I want to make database inserts or selections from. 
So if I need to make a insertion on lets say login_do.php I will just include the database file in like this

```
<?php 
include_once 'databaseConn.php'; 
.
.
. and so on ...
```

And try making your SQL statement like this.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username,email,company) VALUES" .
                 "('".$userName."','".$email."','".$company."')";
```

You need to specify to which index in the database you are sending some value and then write them in the same order.

I hope this works for you and I answered your question. Good luck and keep coding ;)